# How to set additional node type options programmatically?

Tags: 7, nodes

When creating a node type programatically, *some* node type options can be set in `hook_node_info`, including `name`, `base`, `description`, `has_title`, `title_label`, `has_body`, and `help`. As far as these node options go, using `hook_node_info` is cleary the canonical way of doing it.

However, some additional node type options *cannot* be set using this hook, and I have not yet found any *canonical* documentation that explains how do do this.

The options I look for a method of setting programatically include:

- whether commenting by default are open or closed;
- whether the node should be published, promoted, sticky and/or have revisions enabled upon creation;
- whether it should display author and date information.

The solution I *currently* use is to set the appropriate database variables in `hook_install` for the module that creates `my_nodetype` to the defaults I want, e.g.:

```
variable_set('comment_my_nodetype', COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED);
variable_set('node_options_my_nodetype', array('status','promote'));
variable_set('node_submitted_my_nodetype', FALSE);
```

I figured out this solution by reading the source code to discover that these database variables determine behavior at runtime.  I've not found documented anywhere how one *should* go about setting these additional node type options.

Is there a *better* way of doing this than the improvised soluton I currently use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way of doing this than the improvised soluton I
>   currently use?

I don't think so. Also I don't find it improvised.

---

Here's a D7 module I once made that creates a new content type: https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-personality-test/blob/master/personality_test.install

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function MYMODULE_install() {
  node_types_rebuild();
  $types = node_type_get_types();

  // Add a body field
  node_add_body_field($types['MY_CONTENTTYPE']);

  // Add custom fields
  add_custom_fields();

  // Default to not to be promoted
  variable_set('node_options_MY_CONTENTTYPE', array('status'));

  // Disable comments
  variable_set('comment_MY_CONTENTTYPE', COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED);

  // Hide date and author information
  variable_set('node_submitted_MY_CONTENTTYPE', FALSE);

  // Disable node preview
  variable_set('node_preview_MY_CONTENTTYPE', 0);

  // Disable menu entry
  variable_set('menu_options_MY_CONTENTTYPE', array(0));
}
```

I experienced just the same and solved it exactly like you via `hook_install`. If I remember it right, I probably found the code in core when looking how the `article` and `page` node types get created.

---

Related: [How to set node type options programmatically](https://www.drupal.org/node/1169864) (where another [tiny module](https://github.com/antipin/drupal.nodetools) gets recommended you'd need to have everything together in `hook_node_info`).